# Prevent serving files until grunt is done

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I have several tasks in grunt which can take some time: concatenating, ngminifying then uglifying. The end result is then used by the sails linker to update my layouts.

Is there anyway to prevent access to any pages before grunt is done with those tasks ? Displaying a custom page maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I use a separate grunt task to build everything for production and use the built files in my ejs templates when in production mode with if/else. Now sails linker is only used in dev.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by using several grunt tasks:
 - One for development which use sails-linker
 - One for production which does nothing
 - One to build my assets (concat, ngmin, uglify) and upload them to S3

In my ejs layouts, I now have if/else which output links to my S3 files for production and sails-linker for development.

If anyone is interested by those tasks, I'll post an example.

Comment: Sure, first, you need the following grunt tasks: *grunt-ngmin* and *grunt-aws*

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/djhi/11280449) to explain the grunt file.

If anything is unclear, ask me :)